# DNN website: Authorized User Configuration expires and user cannot login

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-settings

A user connot login because it is not set to authorised.

The problem is. When I tried to Authorized the user on the admin panel (Admin>User Accounts>Edit and click the 'Authorize User') its working fine. I tried to login the user credentials and its successfull. However, after how many hours the said user cannot login and I checked the UserAccounts module (Admin>User Accounts>) and I've noticed that the user is not auhorized anymore.

How come that the user is not authorized anymore? Is there a feature of the DNN that expires the authorization of the one user? What should be the cause of this? Should I configure anything on the Settings to prevent this? I am new to DNN CMS.

Please advice. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done if/when the user has a number of invalid login attempts.  You might check the aspnet_membership table for this user and see if they are failing on login repeatedly